# Trying to monitor HTTPs traffic from an Android App using HoneyProxy, figure out the certificates.

Tags: android, windows, ssl, ssl-certificate, mitmproxy

I am on a Windows PC and would like to monitor HTTPs traffic from my Android phone from a particular app. I installed Honeyproxy and set a proxy address on my android device using Proxy Settings app. I am able to see the GET traffic of my phone. Next, to get the HTTPS traffic, I installed the user trusted certificates as described here: http://wiki.cacert.org/FAQ/ImportRootCert#Android_Phones_.26_Tablets

I can confirm that I can see both certificates (root and class3) in the "user trusted certificates" list in Settings> Security. Next I ran the honeyproxy expecting to see the HTTPS traffic this time but there is none.

Further, no HTTPs link from the device opens (I get a certificate untrusted). What is the step I am missing? Do let me know your thoughts!

Comment: I would recommend trying out mitmproxy instead, which nowadays has a much better onboarding mechanism with mitm.it: http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/latest/certinstall.html

Comment: What I missed was to install the corresponding certificates in the windows PC as well. @MaximilianHils thanks for the suggestion, mitm.it is great, but painful to install on windows (from what i understand). honeyproxy worked alright for me.